# securing RESTful API against JSONP data thievery

Tags: javascript, json, security, rest, jsonp

As defined in [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), an evil site might attack the good site by including a script tag:

```
<script type="application/javascript"
    src="http://server.example.com/Users/1234?jsonp=parseResponse">
</script>
```

which would access the user secret data from the good site, if the attacked user has authorized to the good site. As far as I know, a script tag can only execute a GET request, not a POST request.

Questions:

1. If a want to secure my RESTful API from any JSONP thievery, is it enough to replace all GET requests into POST requests?
2. I guess this doesn't prevent from other XSRF attack vulnerabilities. If I have a POST/PUT/DELETE/OPTIONS-only API, what attacks shall I still consider?

PS any valuable links are welcome in the comments.

Comment: This is a good start - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#JSON_encoding

Comment: Well... As a start.. the good site can ( good site will set this optional header in all of its responses ) check the header - HTTP_Referer - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer